# Oracle UNION ALL query takes temp space

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST2 on TEST1.ID=TEST2.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TEST3 LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST4 on TEST3.ID=TEST4.ID;
```

The behavior I see here is, it first join TEST1 and TEST2 tables (billions of rows) and then stores the output in temp tablespace. Then it joins TEST3 and TEST4 and then saves the output in same temp table. And finally select the records from there to display the result.

This behavior I see in both Redshift and Oracle. I was just wondering why it stores the result in temporary segments after getting result from first SELECT. It's time taking as well as eats up the temp space. Can not it just starts displaying the result after 1st SELECT is finishes and then goes for 2nd one (instead of storing).

Comment: Each of the two queries in the union all generates a result set, and that data has to go somewhere.  Where would you like it to go?

Comment: When we execute "SELECT * FROM T". It just chunks out the data from disk, sends it to buffer and then send to client. Why incase of UNION ALL, it collects data from both the SELECTs (stores in memory/disk) and then start chunking the data, why not one why one.

Comment: Your query has **not a valid syntax** - do you mean a `CROSS JOIN` or `JOIN`and you ommit the `ON` predicate?

Comment: corrected the syntax.

Comment: if you take a step back and consider what you are trying to actually achieve, perhaps there is a better way. If this applies to you then feel free to update your question accordingly

Comment: Your query requests the result of the union of the two queries. In order to calculate that result, the query engine must calculate both intermediate result sets and then append them together to make the final result set. Only then can it return that result to the client application. Using temporary space to store intermediate results is a key part of how most database engines work, it's up to the query designer to ensure that this is done in the most efficient manner e.g. by using appropriate filters (and indexes if available) so that the minimum amount of data is being selected efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat speculative, because I don't have an Oracle doc reference.  By inspection, we can imagine instead that you wanted to run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 JOIN TEST2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TEST3 JOIN TEST4
ORDER BY some_col;
```

It should be clear that to apply any set operation like `ORDER BY`, all the records returned from the union query would need to be in one logical place.  A temp table would seem to work.

That you are *not* using `ORDER BY` appears to not affect the workflow which Oracle is using.

I can also add another reason why Oracle is insisting on using a temp table here.  Suppose it would be possible to write both halves of the union directly to the buffer.  But what would happen if, at a later date, the size of the total union query suddenly exceeded what the buffer can hold?  The answer is that your database would crash.  So, using a temp table is a safe bet which should generally always work.

Comment: Yes, the example you mentioned , it is valid to store the result. But incase they are just plane two or more SELECT with UNION ALL, why it stores result. I am asking this because my query is a data warehouse query working on TBs of table and hence eating lot of temp space,

Comment: I agree. There are lot of questions to be answered like 1) In serial execution what will happen after 1st select data is pushed to client and 2nd query taking time to produce the result. client is waiting now after getting half result. 2) In parallel execution how data will be pushed to client. Is it single buffer for all SELECTs or they are pusing data to client independently.  Though anyways the temp space issue remains same for TBs of tables joins and for simple UNION ALL queries.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you *observe this behaviour?* By any chance don't you perform `INSERT` or `CREATE TABLE`? That would explain your observation, because at the end, *all rows* are required.

Also if your client has set an option `fetch all rows` this could be observed.

But in normal case, where the client is interested in *few first rows* **Oracle returns quickly the first available (array size) rows from the first join** ignoring the second one.

You may perform *this little Gedankenexperiment*:

```
create table test1 as 
select rownum id,
lpad('x',1023,'X') pad
from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
```

Create analog the table 2 to 4.

Now run your query (adapted to valid syntax)

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 CROSS  JOIN TEST2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TEST3 CROSS  JOIN TEST4;
```

This returns for my the first page in SQL Developer in ca 30 seconds, which somehow disproves your claim.

Simple calculate the required TEMP space for two 10**6 * 10**6 cartesian join with row lenth 1K - this is far above my TEMP configuration.

The one possible way to observe what is **Oracle actualy doing** is to run the query with the `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` hint.

Than get the `SQL_ID` of the statement and check the actual rows `A-Rows`in the plan

```
 select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('a9y62gxagups6',null,'ALLSTATS LAST')); 


SQL_ID  a9y62gxagups6, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * FROM TEST1 CROSS  JOIN TEST2 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TEST3 CROSS  JOIN TEST4

Plan hash value: 1763392637

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  | Writes |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |       |      1 |        |     50 |00:00:28.52 |     166K|    166K|    142K|       |       |          |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL            |       |      1 |        |     50 |00:00:28.52 |     166K|    166K|    142K|       |       |          |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|       |      1 |   1000G|     50 |00:00:28.52 |     166K|    166K|    142K|       |       |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TEST1 |      1 |   1000K|      1 |00:00:00.02 |       4 |     28 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   4 |    BUFFER SORT        |       |      1 |   1000K|     50 |00:00:28.49 |     166K|    166K|    142K|  1255M|    11M|   97M (0)|
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | TEST2 |      1 |   1000K|   1000K|00:00:03.66 |     166K|    166K|      0 |       |       |          |
|   6 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|       |      0 |   1000G|      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   7 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TEST3 |      0 |   1000K|      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   8 |    BUFFER SORT        |       |      0 |   1000K|      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |      0 |  1103M|    10M|          |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | TEST4 |      0 |   1000K|      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |      0 |       |       |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You see, that Oracle

1) full scanned the table2  (row 5)

2) get one row from table1  (row 3)

3) to return to frist 50 rows (row 0)

4) tables 3 and 4 are untached (rows 7 and 9)

You may simple adapt the example to you inner join to see similar results.